# Include keywords dictionary in document classification using PySpark code

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to perform a document classification using PySpark.

I am using the below steps for that:

```python
# Tokenizer

tokenizer = Tokenizer().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("words")

# Stop Word removal

    updated_stopwords_list = list(set(StopWordsRemover().getStopWords() + 
    custom_stopword_list))

remover_custom = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="words", outputCol="filtered", 
stopWords=updated_stopwords_list)

# HashingTF

hashingTF = HashingTF().setNumFeatures(1000).setInputCol("filtered").setOutputCol("rawFeatures")

# IDF

idf = 
IDF().setInputCol("rawFeatures").setOutputCol("features").setMinDocFreq(0)
pipeline=Pipeline(stages=[tokenizer,remover_custom,hashingTF,idf])
```

And I am using it in a pipeline.

Now, Here after the removing the stop words, I want to include a keyword dictionary(data dictionary) so that it will select the words from the array(out put of stopword remover is an array of words) which is present in that dictionary.

Can anyone please guide me in how to do this? I am reading the keyword dictionary from a CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not required to use HashingTF here is one option using the CountVectorizer by forcing the vocabulary to be your keywords list:

```
# Prepare keyword list to go into CountVectorizer. Can also use Tokenizer if your keywords are only single words
str_to_arr_udf = udf(lambda s: [s], ArrayType(StringType()))

# Fit CountVectorizer to keywords list so vocabulary = keywords
keyword_df = spark.read.format("csv").load(csv_file)
keyword_df.withColumn("filtered", str_to_arr_udf("keyword"))
cv = CountVectorizer(inputCol="filtered", outputCol="filtered_only_keywords", binary=True)
cvm = cv.fit(keyword_df)

# Transform the actual dataframe
cv.transform(df_output_from_stopwords)
```

Otherwise the udf route is always an option. Something like:

```
keyword_list = [x.word for x in spark.read.load(file).collect()]
keep_words_udf = udf(lambda word_list: [ word for word in word_list if word in keyword_list], ArrayType(StringType()) )
```

Assuming this key words list does not contain any words in the StopWordsRemover list, the StopWordsRemover step is actually unnecessary.

Comment: Hi ayplam, thanks for your reply. I am using the stopwords parameter as mentioned in the question. It removes the stopwords from the tokenized output. I am not looking for something to remove from my array. I want to select only the words from the array using the keywords. So I can't use it in stopwords because it will remove those words. I want to keep the words by referring to keyword dictionary. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Thanks a lot ayplam..I tried the udf and it's working as expected..Also you are right about the stopwords remover, I can avoid that step :-)